# Dispatch database data to several consumer in different format

Tags: c#, .net, database, web-services, biztalk

I've a big database which contains a lot of data from a big enterprise.

We would like to be able to dispatch this data to different external applications (external, meaning that are not developed by us, but only accessible in our local network).

Consumers can be of very different kinds: accounting, reporting, tech(business), website, ...

With a big variety of formats: CSV, webservice, RSS, Excel, ...

The execution of these exports can be of two different types: scheduled (like every hour), or on demand.

There is mostly two kind of exports: almost-real-time-data(meaning we want to have current data), or statistical data(meaning we are taking in account a period of time).

I've yet to find a good approach to allows those access.

I thought about Biztalk, but I don't know this product very well, and I'm not sure it can make scheduled calls and have business logic. Does anyone have enough knowledge of Biztalk to indicate to me if it can fit my needs?

If Biztalk isn't a good way, is there any libraries which can ease the development of a custom service?

Comment: Why don't you write a Windows service to do the scheduling?

Comment: Will the data be requested, do you have to publish it, or both? BizTalk can help, you can create an adapter per required output type and there are libraries that can pull data out at scheduled times.

Comment: If its just reporting then SSRS can be a suitable candidate for you. It can do both:Scheduled and On-Demand. On-Demand is straight-forward as the reports can be exposed via a web server. For scheduled, please see [Delivering reports through subscriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159762(v=sql.90).aspx). But if you are looking at a whole solution, of gathering the data from various applications and building a consolidated database for reporting, Biztalk can be of use as well.

Comment: @user1826905 SSRS is not an option, like I said, I've to put this service available for third party apps. The source is only our database, the destination is very different

Comment: @CodeCaster Mostly requested, maybe sometimes published(but if it's the case and that biztalk has no integrated way of doing it, I can do something to make the call)

Comment: You might consider posting this on serverfault as that user base may have more experience with biztalk. Stackoverflow is a little more focused on the programming side how to make those pieces than whether there is an existing out of box solution to your needs. - I would of course write the whole thing from scratch being a programmer, but there may be cheaper ways of accomplishing your needs.

Comment: This question is too vague. Do the clients request data, or do they expect it to be delivered? How? How are they fed at the moment?

Comment: Then the best thing for you is to breakdown your task and see how the 3rd party apps will be consuming this data, in terms of connectivity and format. If its data intensive and something like dropping these exports to a file location, SSIS can also be a candidate, which can produce Excel ( which Biztalk cannot produce out of the box).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Biztalk can be made to do what you want to do i.e. Extract data from your database, transform it into various formats and send it to various systems on a scheduled basis or as and when required by exposing this as a webservice/WCF Service (Not entirely out of the box, but you might need to purchase additional adapters, pipelines, etc).

But, the question here is, how database intensive is this task? If its large volumes of data, clearly Biztalk is not a favorite candidate, as Biztalk struggles with large data. Its good for routing (without transforming/inspecting) though, even if its large data files.

SSIS, on the other hand is good for data intensive tasks. If your existing databases are on SQL Server, then it fits even better for your data intensive exports/imports and transformations. But it falls short when it comes to the variety of ways you need to connect to external systems (protocols).

So, you are looking at a combination of a good ETL tool, like SSIS, as well as something good at routing like Biztalk. Neither of them clearly fit your needs on their own, in terms of scalability, volumes, connectivity, data formats, etc.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. The volume of data is not huge, I'm not affraid of this(and maybe there will be an intermediate database which will already get all data and pre-format data. And in all case, those data will not be used for real time application. So you confirm me that biztalk can schedule some exports?

Comment: Yes, to an extent. The receive location has a basic schedule window, which tells when to activate. The schedule window is for anytime in a day and this applies to all days in a week.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can result in quite a broad implementation.  You could consider using a service bus (pub/sub) along with some form of CQRS (if applicable).

My FOSS Shuttle ESB project is here: http://shuttle.codeplex.com/

It has a generic scheduler built in.  You could, of course, go with any other service bus such as MassTransit, or NServiceBus.

Comment: What is CQRS and FOSS? So biztalk is not applicable? If we need to use a third party software, we have to ensure it is working for years and well supported(restriction of our customer)

Comment: FOSS = Free Open-Source Software.  CQRS (Command / Query Responsibility Segration).  You'll probably want to do an Internet search on CQRS if you are not familiar with it.  I don't know BizTalk so I cannot say whether it can do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use ASP.NET MVC API. http://www.asp.net/web-api 
I find it the easiest way to export different kind of info and file formats.

It won't generate scheduled reports or files, you will need the client app or a windows service to call the app. Similar to webservices, but it can return different formats and also files.

And creating excel files, etc. you have to create them manually. Thats a bit of a turndown, but i like this approach because it can be easily hosted on IIS and all the functions your clients are going to call can be on the same place and even called from javascript, so as i see it is a bit more work for you, but it creates really easy to consume services.

Answer (score 0):

By dispatch, I'm assuming you're looking for a pub/sub model.  Take a hard look at NServiceBus's (NSB) pub/sub capabilities, http://nservicebus.com/docs/Samples/PublishSubscribe.aspx.  Underneath the covers NSB makes heavy use of MSMQ, which has become a lot more stable over time.

If you want to venture outside of your .NET comfort zone, check out [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) or Fuse's [Enterprise Service Bus](http://fusesource.com/open_source/enterprise-service-bus/).  Either of these tools will support what you need as well.  I've used Camel in some extremely high throughput areas without any major issues.